# TcpOutboundGateway- Received alert message close notify after getting response from server?

Tags: java, spring-integration

I am trying to communicate with a tcp server using SSL .And im using outbound gateway for this communication. I am able to send message through connection but after getting response like 1 sec later response is being deserialized by ByteArraySerializer and after like 5 seconds later getting below warning;

```
    Received alert message (
"Alert": {
  "level"      : "warning",
  "description": "close_notify"
}
```

and then facing socket is closed exception.

```
    2021-04-25 **22:56:27**.470 DEBUG 3784 --- [pool-7-thread-1] .p.a.c.i.t.s.ByteArraySerializer : Message(read) bytes:****** 1458****2
javax.net.ssl|FINE|5D|pool-7-thread-1|2021-04-25 **22:56:32**.486 TRT|Logger.java:765|Received alert message (
"Alert": {
  "level"      : "warning",
  "description": "close_notify"
}
)
javax.net.ssl|FINE|5D|pool-7-thread-1|2021-04-25 22:56:32.487 TRT|Logger.java:765|duplex close of SSLSocket
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|5D|pool-7-thread-1|2021-04-25 22:56:32.487 TRT|Logger.java:765|outbound has closed, ignore outbound alert message: close_notify
javax.net.ssl|FINE|5D|pool-7-thread-1|2021-04-25 22:56:32.487 TRT|Logger.java:765|close the underlying socket
javax.net.ssl|FINE|5D|pool-7-thread-1|2021-04-25 22:56:32.487 TRT|Logger.java:765|close the SSL connection (passive)
javax.net.ssl|FINE|5D|pool-7-thread-1|2021-04-25 22:56:32.487 TRT|Logger.java:765|close inbound of SSLSocket
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|5D|pool-7-thread-1|2021-04-25 22:56:32.488 TRT|Logger.java:765|SSLSocket duplex close failed (
"throwable" : {
  java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
    at java.net.Socket.shutdownInput(Socket.java:1539)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.shutdownInput(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.shutdownInput(SSLSocketImpl.java:643)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.bruteForceCloseInput(SSLSocketImpl.java:598)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.duplexCloseOutput(SSLSocketImpl.java:558)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.close(SSLSocketImpl.java:471)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection.close(TcpNetConnection.java:85)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpConnectionSupport.closeConnection(TcpConnectionSupport.java:164)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection.handleReadException(TcpNetConnection.java:235)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection.run(TcpNetConnection.java:182)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)}

)
```

Normally after deserializing message should be sent to another channel to continue but its waiting after deserializing and throwing error above. How can i exceed this problem? My configuration is below;

```
  <int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="tcpClientFactory"
                                   type="client"
                                   host="IP"
                                   port="PORT"
                                   so-timeout="45000"
                                   so-keep-alive="true"
                                   single-use="false"
                                   ssl-context-support="sslContextSupport"
                                   serializer="messageSerializer"
                                   deserializer="messageSerializer"/>


    <ip:tcp-outbound-gateway id="outboundGateway"
                             connection-factory="tcpClientFactory"
                             request-channel="toTcpAdapterChannel"
                             reply-channel="fromTcpAdapterChannel"
                             auto-startup="true"
                             request-timeout="45000"
                             remote-timeout="45000"
                             reply-timeout="45000"/>
```

Comment: It probably means the server closed the socket - examine the TCP traffic using something like WireShark.

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell, i realized that socket is being closed by my side because of having null pointer error.